# Angular CSS property values are joined with spaces are gone in production

Tags: css, angular, primeng, cloudflare

**Honestly I dont know how to describe this error on css. Let's take a look at the image.**

[image: Unusual css in Angular project]

Chrome and Firefox latest
Angular 16
Primeng: 16
Server: cloudflare

`package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^16.2.12",
  "@angular/cdk": "^16.1.7",
  "@angular/common": "^16.2.12",
  "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.12",
  "@angular/core": "^16.2.12",
  "@angular/forms": "^16.2.12",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.12",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.12",
  "@angular/router": "^16.2.12",
  "@microsoft/signalr": "^6.0.10",
  "exceljs": "^4.3.0",
  "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
  "guid-typescript": "^1.0.9",
  "html2canvas": "^1.4.1",
  "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
  "material-icons": "^1.10.8",
  "primeflex": "^3.3.1",
  "primeicons": "^6.0.1",
  "primeng": "^16.7.2",
  "rxjs": "^6.6.0",
  "tslib": "^2.3.0",
  "zone.js": "^0.13.1"
}
```

When purged cache on cloudflare, style loaded as normal.
After few times page refresh, this unusual happens.

Anyone experienced this? Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Check if you have Auto Minify enabled in CloudFlare (check the setting, as well as any page rules that may have the setting enabled as well) https://developers.cloudflare.com/speed/optimization/content/auto-minify/ I've never heard of that setting doing what you describe, but it is the only thing I can think of that may be doing it.

Comment: @MarkB Thank you for answer. I disabled the Auto-minify feature and seems it works.
Very appreciate, thanks much.